# MapFragment is displaying but can't add markers, move camera, etc. with Google Map

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I'm making an application using Android Studio and even though I've got the map and it's being displayed, I can't add markers or do anything else to it using the GoogleMap object obtained from OnMapReady.

Here's the code from my Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener, OnMapReadyCallback {
    MapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        switchFragments(GlobalConsts.FRAGMENT.MAP);
    }
    public void switchFragments(GlobalConsts.FRAGMENT fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (fragment) {
            case MAP:
                if (mapFragment == null) {
                    mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                }
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                break;
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(sydney)
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("Population: 4,627,300")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(sydney).zoom(12).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    }
}
```

Here's the xml layout for my Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    tools:context="jarett.familymap.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

My MapFragment class:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {

    public MapFragment() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and the xml layout for my MapFragment in fragment_map.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            tools:context="jarett.familymap.MapFragment">

</fragment>
```

Like I said, everything seems to be working fine as far as displaying the map fragment but for the life of me I can't figure out why the code for zooming and adding markers isn't doing anything. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figure out why the code for zooming and adding markers isn't doing anything

Well, you have two maps. Your `MapFragment` extends `SupportMapFragment`, so that will give you one map. Then, your `MapFragment` inflates a layout that, in turn, creates a `SupportMapFragment`. This gives you two maps.

Either:

- Delete `MapFragment` entirely, along with its associated layout file, and just have your activity create a `SupportMapFragment`, or
- Delete your `onCreateView()` method from `MapFragment`, and move your map-management code into `MapFragment`, triggered by a `getMapAsync()` call in `onViewCreated()` (as I worry that you are calling it too soon in your existing code)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I just deleted onCreateView() and now it's working exactly as it's supposed to. Thanks for rescuing me, I was losing my mind here.